# Django Relationship to link two models

Tags: django

i am learning django and I am working on an project to make a pizza ordering portal.

I decided to make models for Toppings and Pizza seperately, so that more toppings can be added later and for pizza to of them can be selected, but I cannot seem to figure out the relation schema that should be used to link these two.

I stumbled upon Foreign key method but that is not I want
Here is the part of code for models:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    first_toppping = models.Topping()
    second_topping = models.Topping()
    # in inches
    size = models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
    price = models.FloatField()
```

Please, suggest a method to link these two.

Comment: Here you should indeed use two `ForeignKey`s: one for the `first_topping`, and one for the `second_topping`. Why do you think that is *not* applicable.

Comment: Foreign key links these two together, but other pizzas should have their toppings too @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: well this is exactly what a `ForeignKey` does: *per* `Pizza`, you can link to two toppings. A foreign key is more or less what a reference is in the "object-oriented world".

Comment: ok, will try this way. Thanks @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that a `Pizza` has two `Topping`s, you should add two `ForeignKey`s to `Topping`:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Topping(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    first_toppping = models.ForeignKey(
        Topping,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        related_name='pizza_first'
    )
    second_topping = models.ForeignKey(
        Topping,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        related_name='pizza_second'
    )

    size = models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
    price = models.FloatField()

    def clean(self):
        # given we want the two toppings to be different
        if self.first_topping_id == self.second_topping_id:
            raise ValidationError(_('Toppings should be different.'))
        return super(Pizza, self).clean()
```

or you can make the `ForeignKey`s nullable, such that if one of the toppings is `NULL`, this thus means that we do not select a first/second topping:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Topping(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    first_toppping = models.ForeignKey(
        Topping,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='pizza_first'
    )
    second_topping = models.ForeignKey(
        Topping,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='pizza_second'
    )

    size = models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
    price = models.FloatField()

    def clean(self):
        # given we want the two toppings to be different
        if self.first_topping_id is not None and self.second_topping_id is not None and self.first_topping_id == self.second_topping_id:
            raise ValidationError(_('Toppings should be different.'))
        return super(Pizza, self).clean()
```

Here we thus model that a pizza links twice to a topping.

Depending on the the application, you might want to allow a user to pick an arbitrary number of toppings, and sometimes it is even possible to pick the *same* topping multiple times.

We can use a [**`ManyToManyField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) for that, and in case we want to be able to add the same topping twice (or more) we can work with a `through` table, like:

```
# a pizza can have the same topping multiple times

class Topping(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class PizzaTopping(models.Model):
    pizza = models.ForeignKey('Pizza')
    topping = models.ForeignKey(Topping)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    toppping = models.ManyToManyField(
        Topping,
        through=PizzaTopping,
        related_name='pizzas'
    )

    size = models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
    price = models.FloatField()
```

Comment: thanks for the help, is there a way to enforce both toppings as unique for a pizza in Foreign key method

Comment: @rohan_aggarwal: unique in what sense: that a pizza should have two *different* toppings, or that each topping can only be used for, at most, one pizza?

Comment: A pizza should have two different toppings

Comment: @rohan_aggarwal: you can enforce this at the Django level (not at the database level, or not without some extra packages) by patching the `clean()` method, as demonstrated in the first code fragment.

Comment: or I  an enforce this in form too

Comment: @rohan_aggarwal: a `ModelForm` will call the `.clean()` of the `Model` object when you save it, so by defining it at the model level, you implictly define it for all `ModelForm`s you make with this model

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correcyly, each pizza has many toppings, so you have to use many to many. This way, you can add as many toppings as you want (0-*)

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
    # in inches
    size = models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
    price = models.FloatField()
```

As you can see in the following example, I create a pizza object and I add as many toppings as I want :

```
pizza = Pizza(name="CheesePizza",size=5,price=25.22)
pizza.save()

topping1 = Topping(name="chocolate")
topping1.save()
topping2 = Topping(name="whataver")
topping2.save()
topping3 = Topping(name="component")
topping3.save()

pizza.toppings.add(topping1,topping2,topping3)
```

Comment: And what if I want to make it 2, like two toppings are must for a pizza will this relationship still hold, or I need extra functioanlity to enforce this rule

Comment: Yes. You will add just two, and you can also make sure that the number of toppings is exactly at least equal to 2

Comment: There can however be a problem here if one can order the same topping twice (some restaurants do this such that "two" equal toppings means the *much* of that topping). This can however be solved with a `through` table.

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi: no, by making the topping name unique, that will restrict the toppings to have unique names, which is a good thing. What I mean is that some pizzas can refer *twice* to the *same* topping.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Do you mean like this ? pizza.toppings.add(topping1) pizza.toppings.add(topping1)

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi: exactly.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think the only way to fix this is in the view by checking each of the pizza toppings and making sure that each topping is not duplicated

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi: no, what I mean is that here you can only add `topping1` once, if you call this twice, the second time it will have no effect. But in some restaurants, you want to add it a second time.